# Stop Joomla from redirecting to livepage!

Tags: joomla-3.x

I got a Live-page (our school's homepage) which I backed up via Akeeba and already restored on my local server which I mage with XAMPP.

Now, when I want to surf my local page through `localhost/schulpage/` then it always instantly redirects me to the live-version of my page `www.example.com`.

The only exception of this is when I surf the back-end `localhost/schulpage/administrator`.

But as soon as I click on login it redirects me to the backend of my livepage again.

How can I fix this? Already spent hours trying to figure it out but I don't have a clue where it comes from.

What have I already tried?

- `.htaccess` files first renamed, then deleted -> nothing changed
- `config.php` checked -> no live-page listed.
- `htacess.txt` renamed, deleted -> nothing changed
- Checked installed plugins, no obvious plugins installed.

Comment: Try clearing the Joomla cache if you haven't already.

Comment: If all else fails, search. Firstly, do a text search in the joomla folder for the domain name. configuration.php is the obvious place, but it could be in a template file or something like that. Then do a mysqldump of the database, then do a text search in the sql file for the domain name. It *will* show up somewhere. And when you know where it is, you can probably work out how to fix it from within Joomla.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons Joomla redirect you to the live site.

1. User plugin - Check if there is any user plugin which redirects user to live site. Try disabling the user plugin under Administrator->Extensions->plugins->select plugin type as user in dropdown
2. Custom module - If you are using any third party then please check it's config setting for user login redirection
3. htaccess - As per your question you already renamed it so it does not cause any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It could be set in redirect component or in some sort of system tools - like Admin tools. Check extensions installed on your school site.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem last week with a client. Remove the value of the `$live_url` from your `configuration.php` file. This should fix the problem.

So you should have something like:

```
public $live_site = '';
```